# How to count the number of series of a bar chart in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am facing the some problems when creating bar chart using `JFreeChart`. 
I have to write a condition according to a number of series available on the bar chart, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Bar charts typically use a [`CategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/CategoryDataset.html), all of which implement the [`KeyedValues2D`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/KeyedValues2D.html) interface. Use `dataset.getRowCount()` to get the number of series. Use `dataset.getColumnCount()` to get the number of distinct categories. Their product is the total number of bars.

As a concrete example, I added a spurious new series to [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java) to get three series (rows) and two categories (columns).

```
private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    …
    dataset.addValue(8000, "Meretricious", "Warm-up");
    dataset.addValue(24000, "Meretricious", "Test");
    return dataset;
}
```

[image]